# Can someone explain to me how scheduling works between a main thread and an NSThread?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsthread, cadisplaylink

For example is it doing something like SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR from pthreads?  Can the scheduling policy be changed?  Can priorities be assigned to the main thread and an NSThread?

Ultimately I would like the main thread to run at 30 Hz with a CADisplayLink.  In addition an NSThread would run at a lower priority.  Ideally the main thread would pre-empt the NSThread to maintain the 30 Hz.  I have no idea if this is possible.